# downgrade Xamarin to version 14.17

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

First of all I am using Windows 10 and VisualStudio 2022 to develop an Xamarin.IOS project, I connect to my Mac from Visual Studio. My Mac runs MacOS 10.15.7 and Xcode 12.4, I am unable to install a newer version of MacOS because there is no newer version supported for my mac.

When I connect to my Mac using Visual Studio it says Xamarin is not compatible with Xcode 12.4, install 12.5 or later. Version 12.4 can couse unexpected warnings or errors.

Then I just click OK and connect. When I want to build my Application it says:
`/Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/RetailApplication.iOS/d967d3a2c8371f3518eeb13eb0586ef2298912b5e49700e0a350cef56add41d4/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png`. When I add an AssetCatalog called Assets and a Iconset called AppIcon with a file in it called Icon1024.png the error goes away. Because the icon gets copied to this exact path on my mac.

But now my error message is `File not found: /Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/RetailApplication.iOS/d967d3a2c8371f3518eeb13eb0586ef2298912b5e49700e0a350cef56add41d4/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/_/114.png`.

I am completly clueless how I am supposed to get a File called like this into a subfolder called `_` and why the error occurs. Never have I ever specified 114.png anywhere in my project.

Now I am wondering if this could happen due to me having an outdated Xcode version. And because I am unable to update my Xcode I was wondering if I can downgrade my Xamarin.IOS version. Because Xamarin Version 14.17 is compatible with Xcode 12.4 https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/ios/release-notes/14/14.17

but Xamarin Version 14.19 requires Xcode 12.5
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/ios/release-notes/14/14.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your asset catalog configuration, Right click your ios project > unload project > and edit the csproj file.
Scroll down and see if there is an ItemGroup with content `'Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/_/114.png'`, find it and delete it, then reload csproj, Clean, Rebuild. (You may have to delete the current assets directory, create a new directory and reassign your icon and splash screen).

The use of new Xamarin.iOS with older Xcode is not recommended. There will be a few potential challenges. For more details, you can refer to the official document: [Can I use an older version of Xcode or Xamarin.iOS? | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/old-version-xcode)